# Umbraco on Kubernetes

Tags: umbraco

Is it possible to run Umbraco-CMS in kubernetes cluster? I do know that Umbraco is based on .NET framework and it's will require the use of windows containers. But I would like to know if this is officially supported by Umbraco.
I'll appreciate any answer.

Comment: https://skrift.io/issues/umbraco-docker-and-kubernetes-should-we-care/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw it. It's pretty old article and still I don't see it as an official solution by Umbraco for a large enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not officially supported.  I doubt getting Umbraco and Kubes working would be that high on the roadmap, compared to porting it to .NET core.  They run Umbraco cloud within Azure so the more well-traveled path is to use Umbraco within an Azure web app.  With Umbraco Cloud, uSync, etc.. it is possible to get near replica environments but it's not what your asking.

As the article in the comment suggests, it may be possible, but, I also think it is just as likely you'll end up with some strange errors.  I'm holding off trying this until the When the .NET CORE version is released

https://umbraco.com/blog/net-core-alpha-release/